# Search affected by encryption?

Tags: encryption

If I choose to use case insensitive deterministic encryption on first and last name for the account and contact object, in addition to encrypting search indexes....should I have any problem searching by first and last name or the name of the account? Just want to verify before going down this road. For example, using the concatenated name, such as “John Smith”.  Contact.name would be encrypted with Case Insensitive Deterministic encryption.

Answer (score 5):

[Deterministic Encryption considerations doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5) is pretty clear on this for compound fields like `Contact.Name` (`Account.Name` is not a compound field)

> Compound Fields
>
> Even with deterministic encryption, some kinds of searches don’t work when data is encrypted with **case-sensitive** deterministic encryption. Concatenated values, such as compound names, aren’t the same as the separate values. For example, the ciphertext for the compound name “William Jones” is not the same as the concatenation of the ciphertexts for “William” and “Jones”.

So, if the First Name and Last Name fields are encrypted in the Contacts object, this query doesn’t work:

```
Select Id from Contact Where Name = 'William Jones'
```

> But this query does work:

```
Select Id from Contact Where FirstName = 'William’ And LastName ='Jones'
```

> **Case-insensitive deterministic encryption supports compound fields**.
>
> UPDATE - In a V46 sandbox, when `Contact.Name` `deterministic, case insensitive` encryption is enabled, the `Contact.Name` field is marked in the metadata as filterable = false meaning you can't do `SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'William Jones'

```
[object Object]: select id, name from contact where name = 'William Jones' ^ 
ERROR at Row:1:Column:36 field 'name' can not be filtered in a query call
```

> You can, however, use global search box, enter `William Jones` and the Contact is found; SOSL works as well

```
FIND {William Jones} in Name Fields Returning Contact
```

I'll file a case to see if this is a doc bug or WAD.

> UPDATE 2
>
> SFDC Support confirms that regardless of case (in)sensitive encryption, on a compound field, you CAN NOT do

```
select id, name from contact where name = 'William Jones'
```

> SFDC Support has raised a ticket with the doc team

Comment: this makes sense, except for the sentence about case-insensitive deterministic encryption supporting compound fields.....shouldn’t SELECT ID FROM CONTACT WHERE NAME ‘William Jones’ work? I am still getting the “can’t be filtered in a query call” error.

Comment: are you testing via Dev Console query editor? or in Apex? and if apex, what version is the class?  Edit your OP to show the state of encryption on Contact.Name

Comment: I am using Dev Console query editor. Also the post above is supposed to say Where NAME = ‘William Jones’

Comment: I am curious if this is expected behavior?? Or is this an issue I should contact support on??

Comment: I'll be trying this in my org tomorrow to see if I can confirm.  We have premier support.

Comment: Thank you @cropredy!  Please let me know.

Comment: Any luck @cropredy?

Comment: See my answer.  I reproduced your observation and filed a case

Comment: Woah! Sorry I missed that @copredy.  Please keep me in the loop.

Comment: @testtesttest - usual T2 run around from SFDC Support (I'm engaged in threaded convo)

Comment: @testtesttest - final answer; see above

Comment: BTW, I put all my queries in a selector class ContactsSelector and in the selectByName method, I use SOSL to find Contacts matching Name and then use SOQL on those results to return the Contact(s) + related object graph